# Unix Timestamp in MySQL phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

is there any possibility that there is a field called 'time' in the table and there are 3 more fields, and when I insert the 3 fields, the time field is set default to fill in the current UNIX Timestamp? It will be much appreciated if you help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just inserted the timestamp from PHP to the table.

Answer (score 0):

exactly there is no any default `unix_timestamp` for mysql. you can set the field as a `datetime` or `timestamp` and set its default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. then use `strtotime` function to change back to unix. or set type to `int` or `bigint` or`double` and use `time()` function on every insert row.

I prefer myself to use second way.